# where can i find sms.db file in my iphone using iPhone app

Tags: iphone, database, sms

I have requirement that is i need to read sms message using in my iphone app. I know this only possible in jailbroken iPhone. My iPhone also jailbroken device. but i not able to get sms.db file. where can i find sms database can any one help me, give me some sample source code.

Answer (score 2):

`sms.db` file is located in `/private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db.` You can simply access it through any favorite program (such as iPhone Explorer) and browse to this location.

**Sample Code :**

```
NSString* path = @"/var/mobile/Library/SMS";
NSError* error = nil;
NSArray* files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
```

Comment: i am used this code my iphone application i not able to find any files in this path.

Comment: @iSaravanan: Are you connected to iPhone ? It'll not work on simulator.

Comment: @iSaravanan: Try with `/var/mobile/Library` and let me know.

Comment: i am getting null value in files array.

Comment: but i am used /var/mobile/ means i am getting following values only ".forward",
    Applications,
    Library,
    Media

Comment: @iSaravanan: and your Library - "Directory" is NULL ?

Answer (score 1):

It's located in `/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db`.

Comment: yes, but i am not get Library directory from mobile directory. this is a my issue.

Comment: @iSaravanan What do you mean by "get library directory from mobile directory"?

Comment: i did not get Library folder in mobile folder.

Comment: @iSaravanan What if you try `NSLog(@"%d", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db"]);`? Do you get 0 or 1?

Comment: @iSaravanan Then you don't have an SMS database on your iPhone.

Comment: @H2CO3: Problem is something else. He's not able to reach `/var/mobile/Library` also.

Comment: @Vin Quite a screwed up system, IDK what OP did with his phone... -.-

Answer (score 0):

Apps run in a sandbox on the iPhone and because of Apple Mobile Security, they do not allow these apps to access private data. This is done to protect the owner.

No one wants a malicious piece of software being ran on their iPhone and reading all their texts. You can, however, run a command on the iPhone or from your computer to copy the files down to a PC. This is what iTunes does to backup SMS messages.

App to private folder communication cannot happen though.