# How to get sent sms count in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, jailbreak

I need to get the sms details from iPhone, that is count of sent and received messages and all messages that are stored in iphone device. I know its not possible but it can only do it for Jailbroken devices. Please anybody help me how can access sms.db with example code.

Comment: it's a regular SQLite database. Open it with any SQLite viewer (iFile can do that) to see how information is stored in it. Then just you use SQLite API to read any information you want. If you are planning to do it for multiple iOS versions you should check sms.db from every iOS version you are planning to support. sms.db in iOS 5 and 6 is using completely different database structure.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16958473/119114), and this [document, which may be somewhat old now](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Messages).